# Windows Phone CustomControl Data Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

It is Windows Phone 8.1 (runtime)

I have some problem of binding custom user controll with list of data. I'll make it simple as I can.

My problem is that somehow if I use DataBind {Binding Something} inside my custom controll it will not work.

I need to transfer binded data (string) to custom controll.

It is strange that if I do not use DataBind, it will work normally. Eg MyCustomControllParameter = "some string" (in my example 'BindingTextValue' property)

Does anyone Know how to bind custom user controll with inside ListView with DataTemplate.

Assume this:

**XAML Test-Main page**

```
<Grid  Background="Black">
    <ListView x:Name="TestList" Background="#FFEAEAEA">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#FF727272">
                    <local:TextBoxS BindingTextValue="{Binding Tag, FallbackValue='aSource'}" local:TextBoxS>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>



    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**XAML Test-Main page c#**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<TTag> tags = new List<TTag>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }


    public class TTag
    {
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }

    private void InitializeAppData()
    {
        TTag tag = new TTag() { Tag = "hello world" };
        tags.Add(tag);
        tags.Add(tag);
        tags.Add(tag);
        TestList.ItemsSource = tags;
    }

         protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        InitializeAppData();
    }


}
```

**User Control XAML:**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="CustomControllTest.TextBoxS"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CustomControllTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF4F4F4F"   >
    <RichTextBlock x:Name="MyTestBlock">
    </RichTextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**User Control c# .cs**

```
    public TextBoxS()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingTextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                     "BindingTextValue",
                                     typeof(string),
                                     typeof(TextBoxS),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string BindingTextValue
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(BindingTextValueProperty) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BindingTextValueProperty, value);
            //This method adds some custom logic into RichTextBlock, pointed correctly
            SetupSpotterBox(value);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set DataContext of MainPage as it isn't set anywhere

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Next **Remove** the following line from your UserControl

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

this is to allow your user control to pick up the correct DataContext eg MainPages

Finally some changes to your UserControl xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App21.TextBoxS"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App21"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" x:Name="root">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTestBlock" FontSize="22" 
               Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=BindingTextValue}" Foreground="Red">
    </TextBlock>                    
</Grid>
```

Note the x:Name="root" for the control itself and I have used a TextBlock just so that I can show the Binding to Text property using ElementName and Dependency Property BondingTextValue.

Comment: No probs don't forget to mark as answer if its fixed the problem or not if it hasn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't must update your control in property Setter. Try this code:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingTextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                 "BindingTextValue",
                                 typeof(string),
                                 typeof(TextBoxS),
                                 new PropertyMetadata(default(string), PropertyChangedCallback));


private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {

    //This method adds some custom logic into RichTextBlock, pointed correctly
    var textBoxS = dependencyObject as TextBoxS;

    textBoxS.SetupSpotterBox((string) args.NewValue);
}


public string BindingTextValue
{
    get { return GetValue(BindingTextValueProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(BindingTextValueProperty, value); }
}
```